# Setgid won't work

Tags: permissions

I'm struggling with the SGID command.

Given the following situation:

```
----rws--- 1 simon simon 233 nov 24 13:52 hosts
```

Why can't a user open/edit this file?

Comment: What is the name of the user opening this file?

Comment: Normally, a group named after a user (`simon` in your case) will only contain that user by default. Are you sure the user opening this file is in the `simon` group?

Comment: @Anthon: alice, she isn't in the simon group.

Comment: @JosephR.: I would like to open/edit the file without being part of the simon group hence why I chose for SGID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SGID bit will not help you edit a file if you don't belong to the group owning it. The SGID bit on files is mainly useful for running a script with the file's group as your EGID (effective group ID).

To open the file, you still need read permissions to it (i.e. either it should be world-readable or you should be a member of its owning group). Similarly, to edit it, you need write permissions to it.